# How is Rhythmbox supposed to work

Tags: rhythmbox

I'm completely confused by this thing.

Every time I play a new song it gets added to a playlist. So, when I want to play one particular song on loop it doesn't work. It goes through every song I ever played one at a time and then loops. I tried creating a new play list with one song but I have no idea how to add a song to a playlist. When I go to Edit -> "Add to Playlist" and click on the playlist I created, nothing happens. When I go to music -> import file and click on a song nothing happens. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I've never understood how Rhythmbox works. I recomend you to test **Xnoise**, a media player with a single playlist. You can install it on Ubuntu from the terminal: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shkn/xnoise sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xnoise You can also find more info [here](http://www.xnoise-media-player.com/).

Comment: Try Banshee or one of the other music players, Rhythmbox is weird and funky.  I never liked it.  (it's buggy, but so is Banshee... :/)